# Why is PL/SQL Bulk DML running slowing for large datasets with parent-child constrained tables?

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, bulk, dml

I have been trying to figure out why this PL/SQL purge script runs slowly for datasets where the record table has a a few hundred thousand or more records.  Prior to script execution, a certain subset of the Record table is flagged for purging - about 75%.

What causes the deletion of the Record_Part table to take so much longer than the other tables?  Is it because it is in the middle of the 3-table parent-child hierarchy?  Am I missing some piece of knowledge here in terms of indexes or constraints?  What can I do to speed up this periodic purging process?

This is an Oracle 10g database.

Thanks in advance for reading my question.

**Schema (Partial):**

- Record table is the parent table
- Record_Part table is the child of Record (Record has many Record_Part)
- Record_Person is the child of Record_Part (Record_Part has many Record_Person)
- The typical ratio is 1:7:9 (record:record_part:record_person)

Record

- PK - sysid
- physicalid
- pending
- purge_in_progress

Record_Part

- PK - Part_pk
- FK - record_sysid

Record_Person

- PK - sysid
- FK - Part_pk

**Runtimes**

50000 record entries

- record_person forall completes in 1:40 min
- record_part forall completes in 1:20 min
- record forall completes in 10 seconds

300000 record entries

- record_person forall completes in 9 min
- record_part forall completes in 2 hours
- record forall completes in 20 minutes

2000000 record entries

- record_person forall completes in 1
  hour
- record_part forall completes in 13
  hours (!)
- record forall completes in 8 minutes

**Index and Constraint DDL**

```
alter table Record add constraint record_REC_PK primary key (SYSID) using index tablespace DB_INDEX1;
alter table Record_Part add constraint RECPART_REC_PK primary key (Part_PK) using index tablespace DB_INDEX1;
alter table Record_Part add constraint RECPART_FK foreign key (RECORD_SYSID) references record (SYSID);
alter table Record_Person add constraint RECPERSON_REC_PK primary key (SYSID) using index tablespace DB_INDEX1;
alter table Record_Person add constraint RECPERSON_FK foreign key (Part_PK) references Record_Part (Part_PK);

CREATE INDEX REC_PURGE_IDX ON record (PURGE_IN_PROGRESS);
CREATE INDEX REC_PHYSID_IDX ON record (PHYSICALID);
CREATE INDEX REC_PENDING_IDX ON record (PENDING);
CREATE INDEX RECPART_RECORD_SYSID_IDX ON Record_Part (RECORD_SYSID);
CREATE INDEX RECPERSON_PARTPK_IDX on Record_Person (PART_PK);
```

**Script:**
(timestamp printing omitted from script below)

```
DECLARE

TYPE sSysid IS TABLE OF record.sysid%TYPE
    INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

TYPE physicalid IS TABLE OF record.physicalid%TYPE
    INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;    

l_sid sSysid;
l_physicalid physicalid;

BEGIN
    SELECT sysid, physicalid
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_sid, l_physicalid
        FROM record
        where purge_in_progress = 1;

FORALL i IN l_sid.FIRST .. l_sid.LAST
    delete from record_person where Part_pk like concat(l_sid(i), '%') or Part_pk like concat(l_physicalid(i), '%');

commit;

FORALL i IN l_sid.FIRST .. l_sid.LAST
    delete from record_Part where record_sysid = l_sid(i);

commit;

FORALL i IN l_sid.FIRST .. l_sid.LAST
    delete from record where sysid = l_sid(i);

END;
/

commit;
```

Comment: Are you really collecting 2 million elements into a collection in one pass rather than using a LIMIT to fetch a smaller number of elements each time?  Have you traced the session to see where the time is being spent?  If so, can you post the tkprof output?

Comment: Thanks Justin.  I ran tests of the script with a rownum limit on the bulk collect to get the runtimes, but I guess I didn't consider or realize how important the collection size is to the execution speed.

Comment: Don't use a rownum limit.  Use the LIMIT clause in your BULK COLLECT.

Comment: Thank you, Justin.  Your comment on commit frequency is also helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the first reply on this thread. As Justin pointed out, you need to use the limit clause to fetch a fixed number of records (100 is the generally used, you can parameterize this and see what works for your situation).

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:5918938803188

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, I am running tests now with a while loop surrounding the bulk collect with a rownum limit.  Question - how frequently should I commit?  Every 100, every 1000, or just once after the while loop?  How does commit rate affect speed in the context of this script?  Thanks!

Comment: @kg - Commits will only slow down your processing.  Only commit when you have completed a logical transaction.  I would assume that would mean in your case that you would only commit once at the end of the process unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Can you disable the FK constraints in a test environment to see if that helps?

Another possibility is to re-create the FK constraints as deferrable, and defer the constraints at the start of the script, e.g.:

```
alter table Record_Part 
      add constraint RECPART_FK foreign key (RECORD_SYSID) 
                                references record (SYSID) DEFERRABLE;
alter table Record_Person 
      add constraint RECPERSON_FK foreign key (Part_PK) 
                                  references Record_Part (Part_PK) DEFERRABLE;

SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;
...run your purge
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL IMMEDIATE;
```

Note that any COMMIT will cause the constraints to be set immediate. You will have to reissue the first set constraints statement after each commit.

The constraints would be my first suspect here.

Comment: Since the purge script will be running concurrently with the app that utilizes these tables, I need to maintain referential integrity at all times.  I do appreciate the info about deferring constraints though, it will be useful to me in the future.  thanks.

Comment: Deferrable constraints are session only - you don't lose your constraint checking in other sessions.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this either!  I'll run a test to see if deferring constraints speeds up the script runtime.